# Footer no ocupa todo el ancho de a pesar de estar el width en 100vh y se superpone al body

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, codeigniter

tengo el siguiente dilema con mi footer y body. Sucede que, estoy desarrollando las siguientes vistas pero en cierta vista (registrar usuario) mi footer cubre parte del body y ademas no ocupa en 100% del ancho, si no, como un 98%. Utilizo bootstrap, css y html y como framework CodeIgniter.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #696969;
    color: #F8F8FF;
}

.contenedor {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
    width: 100vw;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Registrar Ciudadano | H.Ayuntamiento de Comalcalco</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="http://www.comalcalco.gob.mx/assets/img/logo_pie.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
   </div>
</header><div class="container">
  <form id="" action="" class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CURP">C U R P</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CURP" placeholder="C U R P">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre (s)">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_M">Segundo Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_M" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Numero Telefonico">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <label>Direccion</label><br>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Municipio</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Mun1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Localidad</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Loc1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc4</a></li>
               </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Colonia</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Col1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col4</a></li>
               </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
   <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   Guardar</button>
</div>
<br>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <footer>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>2016-2018 &copy; Ayuntamiento Constitucional de Comalcalco.
            Todos los Derechos Reservados.</h4>
            </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
       <h2 class="title">Contactanos</h2>
       <p>Plaza Juárez S/N, Col. Centro. Comalcalco, Tabasco </p>
       <p>Código Postal: 86300</p>
       <p>Teléfono: (933)114-00-00</p>
       <p>Correo Electrónico: <a href="presidencia@comalcalco.gob.mx">presidencia@comalcalco.gob.mx</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="http://www.comalcalco.gob.mx/assets/img/logo2-default.png">
      </div>
  </footer>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Siempre que yo trabajaba en alguna web y tenía algún problema parecido era porque habí algún div o el mismo body que tenía por ahí algun margin o padding. Mira uno por uno y seguro que lo encuentras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes usar .container-fluid dentro de un .container y conseguir lo que estás tratando de lograr. Mira el código para la clase .container de Bootstrap. tiene una anchura fija.

```css
html {
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
}

body {
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #696969;
color: #F8F8FF;
}

.contenedor {
position: relative;
width: 100vh;
}

footer {
  
width: 100vw;
background: black;
color: white;
text-align: justify;
position: absolute;
bottom: 50;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Registrar Ciudadano | H.Ayuntamiento de Comalcalco</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="http://www.comalcalco.gob.mx/assets/img/logo_pie.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
   </div>
</header><div class="container">
  <form id="" action="" class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CURP">C U R P</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CURP" placeholder="C U R P">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre (s)">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_M">Segundo Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_M" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Numero Telefonico">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <label>Direccion</label><br>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Municipio</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Mun1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Localidad</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Loc1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc4</a></li>
               </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Colonia</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Col1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col4</a></li>
               </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
   <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   Guardar</button>
</div>
<br>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <footer>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>2016-2018 &copy; Ayuntamiento Constitucional de Comalcalco.
            Todos los Derechos Reservados.</h4>
            </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
       <h2 class="title">Contactanos</h2>
       <p>Plaza Juárez S/N, Col. Centro. Comalcalco, Tabasco </p>
       <p>Código Postal: 86300</p>
       <p>Teléfono: (933)114-00-00</p>
       <p>Correo Electrónico: <a href="presidencia@comalcalco.gob.mx">presidencia@comalcalco.gob.mx</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="http://www.comalcalco.gob.mx/assets/img/logo2-default.png">
      </div>
  </footer>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, fue de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un `display:block;`
y sacalo del contenedor.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es el mal uso de los container y container-fluid en el footer,espero haber corregido tu problema, te dejo una guia: https://www.cubicfactory.com/bootstrap-entender-el-modelo-de-rejilla/

```css
html {
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
}

body {
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #696969;
color: #F8F8FF;
}

.contenedor {
position: relative;
width: 100vh;
}

footer {
  
width: 100vw;
background: black;
color: white;
text-align: justify;
position: absolute;
bottom: 50;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Registrar Ciudadano | H.Ayuntamiento de Comalcalco</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="http://www.comalcalco.gob.mx/assets/img/logo_pie.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
   </div>
</header><div class="container">
  <form id="" action="" class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CURP">C U R P</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CURP" placeholder="C U R P">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre (s)">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_P">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_P" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ap_M">Segundo Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ap_M" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Numero Telefonico">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <label>Direccion</label><br>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Municipio</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Mun1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mun4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Localidad</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Loc1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loc4</a></li>
               </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Colonia</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopu="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Col1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Col4</a></li>
               </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<br>
<div class="container">
   <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   Guardar</button>
</div>
<br>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <footer>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>2016-2018 &copy; Ayuntamiento Constitucional de Comalcalco.
            Todos los Derechos Reservados.</h4>
            </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
       <h2 class="title">Contactanos</h2>
       <p>Plaza Juárez S/N, Col. Centro. Comalcalco, Tabasco </p>
       <p>Código Postal: 86300</p>
       <p>Teléfono: (933)114-00-00</p>
       <p>Correo Electrónico: <a href="presidencia@comalcalco.gob.mx">presidencia@comalcalco.gob.mx</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="http://www.comalcalco.gob.mx/assets/img/logo2-default.png">
      </div>
  </footer>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/proyecto/btstrp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, si, el problema era con eso.